# Can creepers destroy spawners

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have found two cave spider spawners that I can connect to eachother, but it is quite a complicated setup, so I am spending a lot of time.

One big problem I am having that the spawners are in a huge dungeon where I get attacked often. I am wondering if a creeper can destroy my spawner when he gets close somehow.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, Creepers can blow up [stone](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Stone) and [cobblestone](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Cobblestone), both of which have [blast resistances](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Explosion#Blast_Resistance) of 30. Since a [spawner](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Monster_Spawner) has a lower blast resistance of 25, it can certainly get taken out by a nearby Creeper blast.

I suggest closing off side tunnels and keeping the area very well lit while you are nearby doing any mining or construction so that Creepers can't spawn. Then remove the lighting near the spawners when you are done (so they can start spawning again).

Answer (score 8):

Yes, (non-charged) creepers have a maximum blast strength of 56 (at point blank range) and monster spawners have a blast resistance of 25, so the explosion can destroy them.

To combat this you can fill the area with water before you fully seal it, as this will reduce the blast strength of the explosion to 0.

As a side note, ghast's fireballs have a strength of 16.42, so cannot destroy spawners.

Sources: [Creepers](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Creeper), [Monster spawners](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Monster_Spawner) and [Explosions](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Explosion)

Answer (score -3):

Yes they can. Just like with factions and other servers.

Comment: This answer is technically correct and corresponds to the accepted answer, but you should expand upon what you mean.  For example, what do you mean by factions and other servers?